# Define different queries for each panel in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Can you define for each panel its own query? For example I have some charts for which I just want to plot two countries whereas for other charts I want to plot different two countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap. Add the query in the queries panel at the top of the screen.
Go to settings for the particular chart and select the query tab.
Here you can enable/disable the required query. By default , all added queries are enabled.